# Chrome/Safari supported way of IMG height/width by percent?

Tags: html, css, image

In Firefox, using `<img width="50%" height="50%" src="derp.jpg" />` seems to be fine, but any other browser doesn't recognize this the way I want it to. Is there a better way of styling this using CSS? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using the `height` and `width` attributes of an element.  If your styling absolutely *must* be inline, you could do this:

```
<img src="derp.jpg" style="width:50%;height:50%" />
```

However, sizing using percents is relative to the parent element: If your `img`'s parent element has no prescribed size, your results will vary wildly.

Answer (score 1):

you could try css, using the max-height and max-width styles